# libcur post file to web server asynchronously doesn't work?

Tags: file, http, post, libcurl

I want to upload file to web server like IIS or Apache through http post. 
The file is larger than 1GB, so I want to upload it asynchronously .
But the code can't work  and never executed to. the callback "readfunc" function?
Is there anything wrong or what I should do?
Thanks very much!

```
size_t readfunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    FILE *f = (FILE *)stream;
    size_t n;

    if (ferror(f))
        return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT;

    n = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, f) * size;

    return n;
}

void curl_post_form()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL* hCurl = curl_easy_init();
    if (hCurl != NULL)
    {
        curl_httppost* pFormPost = NULL;
        curl_httppost* pLastElem = NULL;

        curl_formadd(&pFormPost, &pLastElem, 
            CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "ufile01", 
            CURLFORM_FILE, "D:\\123.iso", 
            CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "application/octet-stream", 
            CURLFORM_END);

        curl_easy_setopt(hCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, pFormPost);
        curl_easy_setopt(hCurl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.138.1:8800/Record/");                         
        /* I want to use my own read function */
        curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, readfunc);
        /* now specify which file to upload */
        curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_READDATA, f);

        curl_easy_setopt(hCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(hCurl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            printf("Error");
        }
        curl_formfree(pFormPost);
        curl_easy_cleanup(hCurl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Comment: You provide the data to send in the `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` option so there seems like nothing for libcurl to use the read callback for!

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Is there anyway I can use both CURLOPT_HTTPPOST option and read callback? Or I can only use HTTP PUT when I want read callback function at the same time?

Comment: I want to upload big files(larger than 1GB) through http, so I need to develop continuous upload when user stop upload and then restart the upload or resume from Network interruption.In that way, users can save their upload time.I'm looking forward your reply.Thanks

Comment: `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` with callback is done with the `CURLFORM_STREAM` option. See the [curl_formadd man page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html).